# ormlite GetLastInsertId gives Specified cast is not valid. error

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am using Ormlite to insert a record as follows:

```
public static Address Add(Address model)
    {
        using (IDbConnection db = DbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
            {
                db.Insert(model);
                var lastId = db.GetLastInsertId();
                model.Id = (int) lastId;
                return model;
            }
    }
```

However on the line `var lastId = db.GetLastInsertId();`

I get the following error:

```
Message: Specified cast is not valid.

Source: ServiceStack.OrmLite

Stacktrace: at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteReadExtensions.GetLongScalar(IDbCommand dbCmd) in c:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\OrmLiteReadExtensions.cs:line 793
at ServiceStack.OrmLite.ReadConnectionExtensions.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn, Func`2 filter) in c:\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\src\ServiceStack.OrmLite\Expressions\ReadConnectionExtensions.cs:line 31
```

this points to the following ormlite code:

```
public static long GetLongScalar(this IDbCommand dbCmd)
    {
        var result = dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (result is DBNull) return default(long);
        if (result is int) return (int)result;
        if (result is decimal) return Convert.ToInt64((decimal)result);
#### this line here is 793 if (result is ulong) return Convert.ToInt64(result);
        return (long)result;
    }
```

The record actually goes into the database just fine, and my first column is int(11) in a mysql database, and is the first column with a name of Id.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Address` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Street` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `StreetTwo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Street 2:',
  `Town` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `City` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `County` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PostCode` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Post Code:',
  `Notes` text,
  `Enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

I use this ormlite with mysql ALL the time, and i have never, ever had this issue, and i am left scratching my head for the first time, in a long time.

I am using the nuget package Ormlite.MySQL  3.9.59   and is the most up to date package available on nuget.

This would not be so strange, if it was not for the records actually going in.  This seems to be some issue with executeScaler and the returned value ????

Any help much appreciated here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is some problem with this version of `ServiceStack.Ormlite`. I am able to reproduce this issue. It will work just by using the previous version.

You can install the previous version using `Nuget Packet Manager Console`. In case, if you don't know how to install old version using Packet  Manager Console, then here it is:

```
Install-Package Package-Name-Here -Version Version-You-Want-To-Install
```

Comment: I had the same problem, and found that the .58 version also has it. Here is what I ran in the package manager console to get this working:
Uninstall-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql;
Install-Package ServiceStack.OrmLite.MySql -Version 3.9.57

Comment: @Robert Thankx for sharing this... I just forgot to mention uninstalling the dependencies before `ServiceStack.Ormlite`

Comment: Nice 1 @Robert with the spot on version 58 not working either.   Thanks guys